# How to track the user activities in Linux?

Tags: linux, security

I would like to have something to monitor the user usage of the computer, for example, what application they had opened, what website they go to. Any software for doing this? Thank you.

Comment: [Parental monitoring](http://superuser.com/questions/346927/surveillance-of-teenagers-keylogging-on-a-machine) and [employee monitoring](http://superuser.com/questions/347828/how-to-monitor-remote-employees) were torn to shreads - expect some serious resistance to this question.